# Store forum subcategories in the same table or in a separate table

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'd like to hear opinions on if it is better to keep forum categories and subcategories in the same table or in two separate tables...

Let's say you have a table ForumCategories. By adding a colum ParentId referencing the PK Id in the same table you could easily keep both the main categories and subcategories in the same table.

Alternatively, you could create a separate table ForumSubCategories and make the Id on that table a FK referencing PK Id column of the ForumCategories table.

Both solutions would work but what are the pros and cons of each solution?

Obviously, this is a more generic question that can apply to many other scenarios I just couldn't come up with a better phrasing in a hurry...

Comment: how many levels do you anticipate ?  If it is more than 2 you might as well go down the heirarchical route, but if it is only 2 then separated tables is a lot simpler.

Comment: I was thinking 2 when I asked but discussing a scenario of more than two is more than welcome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any benefits of using 2 tables.  Using 2 tables is going to constrain you to a 2 level tree.  If you look at things as objects, then subcategories really are just category object. So put them in the same table. The 1 table structure will be simpler to design around and develop queries for.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that your forums will have only 2 levels of categories, then having 2 tables is reasonable.

Though storing categories in one table with foreign key to itself, basically, allows you store a tree of categories with virutally unlimited levels.

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same entity (Category), you can link to itself. The parent would have a null for the parent ID or it could be linked to itself. This limits you to only one level unless you have a second table to handle the many-to-many possible relationships.

They must have the same fields or you're going to have unecessary fields for one or the other type. A separate table is why you would do this because they're not the same.

This is typical for an employee table. The supervisor is another employee record.